# group rows on basis of columns value match

Tags: python, pandas

I have df like this . I want to group row of id & times values matches. I tried groupby but  was unable   .

```
 >>> df
       number title   id       time
    0      10    aa  100  02.05.2018  04
    1      11    bb  100  02.05.2018  04
```

desired output

```
>>> df
       number   title   id     time
0      10 11    aa bb  100  02.05.2018  04
```

Please help in solving this.

Thanks

Comment: So need lists or strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by chance you were looking for lists

```
df.set_index(['id', 'time']).groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(
    lambda d: pd.Series(d.to_dict('l'))
).reset_index()

    id           time    number     title
0  100  02.05.2018 04  [10, 11]  [aa, bb]
```

Answer (score 1):

Need [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `join` and `astype` for convert numeric columns:

```
df = df.groupby(['id','time'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str)))
print (df)

    id            time  number  title
0  100  02.05.2018  04   10 11  aa bb
```

Or convert all columns without grouped to `str` first:

```
df[df.columns.difference(['id','time'])]=df[df.columns.difference(['id','time'])].astype(str)
df = df.groupby(['id','time'], as_index=False).agg(' '.join)
print (df)

    id            time  number  title
0  100  02.05.2018  04   10 11  aa bb
```

If not convert all numeric columns are silently dropped:

```
df = df.groupby(['id','time'], as_index=False).agg(' '.join)
print (df)

    id            time  title
0  100  02.05.2018  04  aa bb
```

And if need filter only some columns:

```
cols = ['number']
df = df.groupby(['id','time'], as_index=False)[cols].agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str)))
print (df)

    id            time number
0  100  02.05.2018  04  10 11
```